# maven deploy-file says it succeeded but no files are actually deployed

Tags: maven

I've build a custom version of an OSS (zookeeper) project and want to deploy it to a local group-wide repository.  So I ran:

> *mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.apache.zookeeper -DartifactId=zookeeper -Dversion=3.4.5.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=./zookeeper-3.4.5.1.jar -DrepositoryId=cabot.maven.repo -Durl=file://xxx/myRepo*

and got lots of success messages:

> *Uploading: file://xxx/myRepo/org/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper/3.4.5.1/zookeeper-3.4.5.1.jar
>   Uploaded:
>   file://xxx/myRepo/org/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper/3.4.5.1/zookeeper-3.4.5.1.jar
>   (1292 KB at 12914.2 KB/sec) Uploading:
>   file://xxx/myRepo/org/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper/3.4.5.1/zookeeper-3.4.5.1.pom
>   Uploaded:
>   file://xxx/myRepo/org/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper/3.4.5.1/zookeeper-3.4.5.1.pom
>   (404 B at 394.5 KB/sec) Downloading:
>   file://xxx/myRepo/org/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper/maven-metadata.xml
>   Downloaded:
>   file://xxx/myRepo/org/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper/maven-metadata.xml
>   (313 B at 43.7 KB/sec) Uploading:
>   file://xxx/myRepo/org/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper/maven-metadata.xml
>   Uploaded:
>   file://xxx/myRepo/org/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper/maven-metadata.xml
>   (313 B at 305.7 KB/sec)*

but no files were actually uploaded...or at least when I go to the repo url I don't see anything.

If an error had been reported I could fix it but in this case there is no error other than the file(s) were not uploaded.  How can I troubleshoot this?

Thanks.

Comment: try adding "-X" to the maven invocation, see if anything interesting appears in the debug output

Comment: Based on the output you need to define the url as **file:///..** instead of **file://**. Furthermore to deploy it to be used in limited gropu the best solution would be to use a repository manager.

Comment: Thank you...I stumbled upon the similar thought..turns out I needed four slashes :-)  Yikes!

Comment: @BrianTarbox Your answer says three; it'd be nice to clarify how many.

Answer (score 0):

khmarbaise was 99% right.  I was using `file://` and should be stated as `file:///`, i.e. (`file://` plus a root `/``)

The files were getting deployed but not to `myRepo` but to `/myRepo` on my local file system.

Comment: We actually are using four slashes in the url for our repo in our pom.xml

Comment: We actually are using four slashes in the url for our repo in our pom.xml

   <url>file:////1.2.3.4/mountPoint/myRepo</url>


and in our maven deploy:deployFile url:
 -Durl=file:////xxx/myRepo

In all honesty I'm not sure why we need four slashes.